# my function only returns the last item in a list

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to read some data from a csv file. The problem is that the list is only displayed when print(a) is under the "if" block
 otherwise , it only dislplays the last item in the list

```
 def products_per_command():
    a=[]
    with open('commande_client.csv') as csv_file:
        Numero_commande=input ('entrez le numero de la commande que vous cherchez :' )
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        for row in csv_reader:
            for i in row:
                if (i==Numero_commande):
                     a=[row[2],row[4]]
                     print(a)
```

the output here is:

```
 entrez le numero de la commande que vous cherchez :1
['af23', '150']
['ab12', '500']
['ab12', '214']
['af12', '21']
['ab12', '526']
['ab12', '223']
```

that's what i actually want but when i put the "print(a)" at the end of my function (not under any loop or "if") it only displays last item :

```
['ab12', '223']
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: how to return all the list and not only the last item

Comment: `print` != `return`. If you want to return the list you have to use the `return` keyword after the loop. `return a`

Comment: when you do `a=[row[2],row[4]]` in your last statement you are replacing completely any previous value  `a` held so `print(a)` here repeatedly prints the updated `a` when in the if statement runs. All memory of the previous `a` is lost when you write a new value so you will need to keep the "`a`"'s in some kind of data structure to access for a later print. The natural thing to reach for is a list and appending repeatedly to this list as @Rakesh suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list.append`

```
def products_per_command():
    a=[]
    with open('commande_client.csv') as csv_file:
        Numero_commande=input ('entrez le numero de la commande que vous cherchez :' )
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        for row in csv_reader:
            for i in row:
                if (i==Numero_commande):
                    a.append([row[2],row[4]])
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i==Numero_commande):
                     a=[row[2],row[4]]
                     print(a)
```

Since this part is inside your loop, you are setting a new value to `a` with each iteration. If you print it in the loop, `a` is printed with its current value every iteration, giving you the whole intended list in the output. Note that the combined list is never saved in memory at once.
However if you print `a` outside the loop, `a` will have the value you assigned to it in the last iteration.

Like others have said, you want to use `a.append()` instead of `a = ...` as this adds to the list instead of overwriting it.